# data.table with rolling join calculating average conditional on date

Tags: r, data.table

I could do this by looping through my dataset multiple times but thought there must be a more efficient way to do this through data.table.
This is what the dataset looks like:

```
CaseID         Won     OwnerID      Time_period    Finished
  1            yes        A              1              no
  1            yes        A              3              no
  1            yes        A              5              yes
  2            no         A              4              no
  2            no         A              6              yes
  3            yes        A              2              yes
  4            no         A              3              yes
  5            15         B              2              no
```

For each row, by owner, I want to generate an average of the amount of cases finished before that time period that are won.

```
CaseID         Won     OwnerID      Time_period     Finished     AvgWonByOwner  
  1            yes        A              1              no            NA
  1            yes        A              3              no             1
  1            yes        A              5              yes           .5
  2            no         A              4              no            .5
  2            no         A              6              yes           2/3
  3            yes        A              2              yes           NA
  4            no         A              3              yes           1
  5            15         B              2              no            NA
```

Looking at this in detail, it seems ridiculously complicated. I thought you might be able to do this with some sort of rolling merge, but I don't know how to set a condition where the average is only calculated from Won before the date of the row and where it has to have the same ownerID.

Edit 1: Explanation for numbers in final column

```
AvgWonByOwner          Explanation
   NA                  t = 1, No cases finished yet, this could be 0 too
   1                   t = 3, case 3 finished and is won, so average wins is 1
  .5                   t = 5, case 3 finished, won; case 4 finished lost; average = .5
  .5                   t = 4, case 3 finished, won; case 4 finished lost; average = .5
  2/3                  t = 6, case 3 finished, won, case 4 finished lost, case 1 finished won, average: 2/3
   NA                  t = 1, No cases finished yet, this could be 0 too
   1                   t = 3, case 3 finished and is won, so average wins is 1
   NA                  t = 1, No cases finished yet, this could be 0 too
```

Comment: you need to explain how you arrived at those numbers in the last column

Comment: Case 1 is finished at point t=5, it doesn't get counted in average until t = 6. Basically it's a strict inequality.

Comment: @Luke +1 for a real head scratcher!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dt = data.table(structure(list(CaseID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5), Won = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("15", "no", "yes"), class = "factor"), 
    OwnerID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
    "B"), class = "factor"), Time_period = c(1L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 
    6L, 2L, 3L, 2L), Finished = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("no", "yes"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("CaseID", 
"Won", "OwnerID", "Time_period", "Finished"), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")))

# order
setkey(dt, OwnerID, Time_period)

# calculate the required ratio but including current time
dt[, ratio := cumsum(Finished == "yes" & Won == "yes") /
              cumsum(Finished == "yes"),
     by = list(OwnerID)]

# shift to satisfy the strict inequality as per OP
dt[, avgWon := c(NaN, ratio[-.N]), by = OwnerID]

# take the first one for each time (that is last one from previous time)
# so that all of the outcomes happening at same time are accounted for
dt[, avgWon := avgWon[1], by = key(dt)]

dt[order(OwnerID, CaseID)]
#   CaseID Won OwnerID Time_period Finished     ratio    avgWon
#1:      1 yes       A           1       no       NaN       NaN
#2:      1 yes       A           3       no 1.0000000 1.0000000
#3:      1 yes       A           5      yes 0.6666667 0.5000000
#4:      2  no       A           4       no 0.5000000 0.5000000
#5:      2  no       A           6      yes 0.5000000 0.6666667
#6:      3 yes       A           2      yes 1.0000000       NaN
#7:      4  no       A           3      yes 0.5000000 1.0000000
#8:      5  15       B           2       no       NaN       NaN
```

Comment: +1 I have *no* idea how you managed to crack this. Very clever.

Comment: I'm not sure this will work if, for instance, there are multiple records with the same `Time_period` for a single `OwnerID`. (The problem is in that "shift" step, which takes a bit of a shortcut...)

Comment: @JoshO'Brien I think it will - there is a step in there to address specifically that issue, but if you think I made a mistake and have an example where it doesn't work I'd love to see it

Comment: @eddi -- Well, I'm doubting myself because it was just my intuition and because it *is* you. But I'll take another minute or two to see where I went wrong ;)

Comment: @eddi -- After loading in `dt`, try doing `dt <- rbind(dt, dt[3,])`, then run the rest of your code. Then compare rows 2, 4, and 8 of  the output (or do `dt[Time_period==3,]`). The values in the `avgWon` column for those three rows should be the same, right??

Comment: @JoshO'Brien an easy fix for the very specific case (which should probably not appear in the data, i.e. same case, same time, same owner, same result?), would just be `dt[ ! duplicated(dt) ]` before you do any processing.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien sorry I'm a bit confused - they *are* the same...? (except `Time_period == 3` for only two rows with just one `rbind`? I feel like we're doing smth different:))

Comment: @eddi -- They weren't the same when I tried using `dt <- rbind(dt, dt[3,])`, but if you say that error will only happen with repeats of same case, same time, and same owner, I'll  trust you.

Comment: haha, ok. As Simon pointed out that's probably not an important case, but fwiw I tried running your answer as well for it (to see if I'm maybe missing smth) and unfortunately it errored out

Comment: @eddi -- Mine just errors out because `dt`'s key gets dropped when doing `dt <- rbind(dt, dt[3,])`. Reset the key and it works for this (admittedly unimportant) case.  I see now, though, what `dt[, avgWon := avgWon[1], by = key(dt)]` does, and why yours thus works. Very clever (even if it is a bit opaque)!

Answer (score 2):

```
## Compute a data.table recording the win percentage at end of each time period
B <- dt[Finished=="yes",]
B[,winpct := (cumsum(Won=="yes")/seq_along(Won)),by=OwnerID]

## Shift forward by one time step, as per OP's description of problem
B[,Time_period := Time_period + 1]
setkeyv(B, key(dt))

## Append win percentage column back to original data.table
cbind(dt, AvgWonByOwner=B[dt, winpct, roll=TRUE][["winpct"]])
#    CaseID Won OwnerID Time_period Finished AvgWonByOwner
# 1:      1 yes       A           1       no            NA
# 2:      3 yes       A           2      yes            NA
# 3:      1 yes       A           3       no     1.0000000
# 4:      4  no       A           3      yes     1.0000000
# 5:      2  no       A           4       no     0.5000000
# 6:      1 yes       A           5      yes     0.5000000
# 7:      2  no       A           6      yes     0.6666667
# 8:      5  15       B           2       no            NA
```